# Why is a monad prototype required for Douglas Crockford's monad demo code?

Tags: javascript, prototype, monads

*Note: while the code in this question deals with functional programming/monads, etc., **I'm not asking about functional programming** (nor do I think this question should have tags related to functional programming, etc.). Instead, **I'm asking about the use of JavaScript's prototype**.*

**Code Source**

I'm watching Douglas Crockford's video entitled "Monads and Gonads" (on YouTube either [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkZFtimgAcM) or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0EF0VTs9Dc)). He includes a demo implementation of a monad in JavaScript, shown below.

**The `monad` Object and its Prototype**

In his code, he creates a truly-empty object using `Object.create(null)` and uses this as the prototype for his eventual `monad` object. He attaches the `bind` method to the monad object itself, but any custom functions that are later attached to the monad using `lift` are attached not to the monad object itself but to its prototype.

**Prototype Needed?**

It seemed to me that the use of a prototype was unnecessary complexity. Why couldn't those custom functions simply be attached directly to the monad object itself? Then, it seemed to me, the prototype wouldn't be needed, and we could simplify the code.

**Puzzling Results When Prototype Removed**

I tried implementing this simplification and got puzzling results. The non-prototype-using code sometimes still worked, i.e. it could still use the monad-wrapped value (the string "Hello world.") when the custom function was invoked with no extra parameters (`monad2.log()`). However, when the custom function was invoked using extra parameters (`monad2.log("foo", "bar")`), the code was now unable to find `value` even though it could still use those extra parameters.

***Update on Puzzling Results:** In part because of the answer from @amon, I have realized that the puzzling results do not appear because I change the number of parameters, but rather because I simply repeat a call to a `lift`ed method on a monad (whether or not the number of parameters has changed). Thus, running `monad2.log()` twice in a row will yield the correct value the first time but will be undefined the second time.*

**Questions**

So, why is the prototype needed in this code? Or, alternatively, how does eliminating the prototype cause `value` to be accessible some times but not other times?

**Demo Code Descriptions**

The two versions of the code are shown below. The prototype-using code (`MONAD1`) is identical to the code Crockford uses in his video except that the custom function attached is `console.log` instead of `alert` so that I could play with this in node rather than in a browser. The non-prototype-using code (`MONAD2`) makes the changes indicated in the comments. The output is shown in the comments.

**The Prototype-Using Code**

```
function MONAD1() {
    var prototype = Object.create(null);       // later removed
    function unit (value) {
        var monad = Object.create(prototype);  // later moved
        monad.bind = function (func, ...args) {
            return func(value, ...args);
        }
        return monad;
    }
    unit.lift = function (name, func) {
        prototype[name] = function (...args) { // later changed
            return unit(this.bind(func, ...args));
        };
        return unit;
    };
    return unit;
}

var ajax1 = MONAD1()
    .lift('log', console.log);

var monad1 = ajax1("Hello world.");

monad1.log();             // --> "Hello world."
monad1.log("foo", "bar"); // --> "Hello world. foo bar"
```

**The Non-Prototype-Using Code**

```
function MONAD2() {
    // var prototype = Object.create(null);      // removed
    var monad = Object.create(null);             // new
    function unit (value) {
        // var monad = Object.create(prototype); // removed
        monad.bind = function (func, ...args) {
            return func(value, ...args);
        }
        return monad;
    }
    unit.lift = function (name, func) {
        monad[name] = function (...args) {       // changed
            return unit(this.bind(func, ...args));
        };
        return unit;
    };
    return unit;
}

var ajax2 = MONAD2()
    .lift('log', console.log);

var monad2 = ajax2("Hello world.");

monad2.log();             // --> "Hello world." i.e. still works
monad2.log("foo", "bar"); // --> "undefined foo bar" i.e. ???
```

**JSBin**

I've played with this code in node, but you can see the results in this [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/hihipaquha/edit?js,console). `Console.log` doesn't seem to work exactly the same in jsbin as it does in node in the terminal, but it still shows the same puzzling aspects of the results. (The jsbin doesn't seem to work if you just click on 'Run' in the console pane. Rather, you have to activate the output pane by clicking on the 'Output' tab, and then click on 'Run with js' in the 'Output' pane to see the results in the 'Console' pane.)

Comment: It's something todo with the relative timing of `Object.create()` and `unit.lift()`, and the `this` referred to in `unit(this.bind(func, args))`. I need to play around with it more to arrive at an explanation of why before I answer

Comment: This is a weird and muddled monad implementation. You should look into [Fantasy Land](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land). There are a lot of clean and concise implementations of various monads.

Comment: @ftor, I've heard of Fantasy Land and will look into it. To give Crockford the benefit of the doubt (which he may or may not deserve, I don't know), I'll guess that his monad implementation _was_ weird and muddled on purpose in order to give functional-programming-newbie JavaScript developers an oversimplified and possibly corrupted starting point just to give us an introduction to monads. Feel free to chime in again if you think that even a simple intro to monads in JS should have been done differently, but in the mean time I'm going to continue pulling this one apart to start to "grok" FP.

Comment: @Andrew First of all I think it's great that you want to grok FP. I am a learner as well. Anyway, a Monad consists of a type (usually a prototype with some attached methods in JS), a composite type that represents an instance of that type (usually an `Object` type in JS) and a specific effect/context, which is the reason why this spcific Monad exisits in the first place. The effect/context determines how `bind` and `unit` have to be implemented. This isn't reflected by Crockford's example - or at least I can't see it.

Comment: @ftor, wrt a specific effect/context... If I understand you correctly, Crockford discusses such things elsewhere in his video. For example, he changes `function MONAD() {...` to `function MONAD(modifier) {...` to allow a modifier function to alter the monad/type. The code I show here is only part-way through the video. As you suggest, his "maybe" monad modifies `bind` to simply return the monad instance in the case of a null value. Anyway, you have also given me helpful categories: type, composite type, specific effect/context. That helps me to classify some of these concepts. Thx again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a clear distinction between a particular type of monad, and a monad instance that actually contains a value. Your second example is mixing the two up in a manner that I'll discuss in a moment.

First, the `MONAD` function constructs a new monad type. The concept “monad” is not a type in itself. Instead, the function creates a type that has monad-like behaviour:

- The `unit` operation wraps a value inside a monad. It is a kind of constructor: `monadInstance = MonadType(x)`. In Haskell: `unit :: Monad m => a -> m a`.
- The `bind` operation applies a function to the value(s) within a monad instance. That function must return a monad of the same type. The bind operation then returns the new monad: `anotherMonadInstance = monadInstance.bind(f)`. In Haskell: `bind :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`.

You can think of the `MonadType` and the `unit()` operation as being more or less the same thing. The reason why we create a separate prototype is that we don't want to inherit random baggage from the “function” type. Also, by hiding it within the monad-type constructor, we protect it from unchecked access – only `lift` can add new methods.

The `lift` operation is not essential, but mightily convenient. It allows functions that works on plain values (not monad instances), to be applied to monad instances instead. Usually, it would return a new function that operates on the monad level: `functionThatReturnsAMonadInstance = lift(ordinaryFunction)`. In Haskell: `lift :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> (a -> m b)`. But which kind of monad is `lift` supposed to return? To keep this context, each lifted function is bound to a particular `MonadType`. Note: not just a particular `monadInstance`! Once a function is lifted, we can apply it to all monads of the same type.

I'll now rewrite the code to make these terms more clear:

```
function CREATE_NEW_MONAD_TYPE() {
    var MonadType = Object.create(null);
    function unit (value) {
        var monadInstance = Object.create(MonadType);
        monadInstance.bind = function (func, ...args) {
            return func(value, ...args);
        }
        return monadInstance;
    }
    unit.lift = function (name, func) {
        MonadType[name] = function (...args) {
            return unit(this.bind(func, ...args));
        };
        return unit;
    };
    return unit;
}

var MyMonadType = CREATE_NEW_MONAD_TYPE()
MyMonadType.lift('log', console.log);  // adds MyMonadType(…).log(…)

var monadInstance = MyMonadType("Hello world.");

monadInstance.log();             // --> "Hello world."
monadInstance.log("foo", "bar"); // --> "Hello world. foo bar"
```

What happens in your code is that you get rid of the `monadInstance`. Instead, you add a `bind` operation to the `MonadType`! This `bind` operation happens to refer to the *last* value that was wrapped with `unit()`.

Now note that the return value of lifted functions is wrapped as a monad with `unit`.

- When you construct the `monadInstance` (which is actually `MonadType`), then `MonadType.bind()` refers to the `"Hello World"` value.
- You invoke the lifted `log()` function. It receives the value within the monad, which is the last value that was wrapped with `unit()`, which is `"Hello World"`. The return value of the lifted function (`console.log`) is wrapped with `unit()`. This return value is `undefined`. You then replace the `bind` function with a new `bind` that refers to the `undefined` value.
- You invoke the lifted `log()` function. It receives the value within the monad, which is the last value that was wrapped with `unit()`, which is `undefined`. The observed output ensues.

Comment: Wow your answer is helpful in so many ways. In any case, when I first posted the question, I was somehow incorrectly thinking that any `MonadType` would only be used to instantiate a single `monadInstance` in some sort of singleton pattern, which I now see is incorrect. I was also misunderstanding what `this` refers to within `unit.lift`, i.e. if the named function is called by a `monadInstance` (which it must be) then `this` refers to `monadInstance` not `MonadType`. Your answer is, among other things, a case study in the value of well-named variables.

Comment: Just a heads-up: In my original question I should have written all instances of `args` as `...args`. (The code doesn't work correctly otherwise.) I've edited my question to reflect this, making 2 changes. You just copied my code, including those mistakes, so you might want to now edit your code answer to include those ellipses. (Oh, and you forgot a 'c' in one 'monadInstane'.) I'll remove this comment after you make those changes. (I didn't want my name, i.e. the OP's name, as an editor of your answer. Just looks bad somehow.)

Comment: @AndrewWillems I fixed the answer as per your suggestion, thanks. I think the code is a very elegant encoding of monads into a dynamically typed language, but it's rather non-obvious. The focus does not seem to lie in teachability, but in thorough encapsulation.